# localStorage data getting lost as soon as browser closed

Tags: local-storage

I'm using firefox 40.0 on ubuntu. I've used localStorage to store some data which works fine. But when I close browser and open again localStorage data gets lost.

Any idea please if I'm doing anything wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please post your code? It will be easier to find out what's going on there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. It was due to https:// and http://. I was saving data on https:// and was trying to access on http:// (on same domain) which was not needed in my case. I accessed this on https:// and all worked fine.

This might help some one :)

Thanks,